# change dropdown menu then scrape data using rvest or httr

Tags: r

I'm scraping data from https://rotogrinders.com/lineups/nfl?site=draftkings. Currently, I use `myData <- read_html("https://rotogrinders.com/lineups/nfl?site=draftkings")` to bring in data, then extract the data I want using `html_nodes`. I'm trying to change the slate selection menu, then grab the data. The XPath for the menu I'm trying to change is `//select[@name='slate_name']`.

My research leads me to believe I need to implement one of the following functions, but I'm unsure how to go about doing it, as the menu is not in a form and there is no submit button... the page automatically reloads once a new option is selected:

```
httr::post
rvest::html_session
Rselenium
```

I'm not familiar with the `Rselenium` library, so ideally I'm looking for a solution using `httr` or `rvest`.

Comment: It is not correct your statement that "the page automatically reloads once a new option is selected".  In fact, changing the slate selection does not trigger a new request, but rather changes (for example) #schedule-45755 from "display:block" to "display:none". If you select slate "all games" then you will make everything visible, but regardless, it is all there in the read_html source code.

Comment: This appears to be a violation of the TOS which includes this prohibition: "Users of the Service may not engage in unauthorized spidering, "scraping", data mining or harvesting of Content, or use any other unauthorized automated means to gather data from or about the Service."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You allready got all the information with via `read_html()`. The slate-name drop-down just filter the schedules via java-script. I would suggest grab all the data and filter by yourself. Hope that helps.

```r
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)
#> Lade nötiges Paket: xml2

url <- "https://rotogrinders.com/lineups/nfl?site=draftkings"
myData <- read_html(url) 

myData %>%
  html_nodes(".teams") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  stringr::str_squish()
#>  [1] "New York NYJ Jets Cleveland CLE Browns"          
#>  [2] "New Orleans NOS Saints Atlanta ATL Falcons"      
#>  [3] "Buffalo BUF Bills Minnesota MIN Vikings"         
#>  [4] "Denver DEN Broncos Baltimore BAL Ravens"         
#>  [5] "Indianapolis IND Colts Philadelphia PHI Eagles"  
#>  [6] "Cincinnati CIN Bengals Carolina CAR Panthers"    
#>  [7] "San Francisco SFO 49ers Kansas City KCC Chiefs"  
#>  [8] "Green Bay GBP Packers Washington WAS Redskins"   
#>  [9] "Oakland OAK Raiders Miami MIA Dolphins"          
#> [10] "New York NYG Giants Houston HOU Texans"          
#> [11] "Tennessee TEN Titans Jacksonville JAC Jaguars"   
#> [12] "Los Angeles LAC Chargers Los Angeles LAR Rams"   
#> [13] "Chicago CHI Bears Arizona ARI Cardinals"         
#> [14] "Dallas DAL Cowboys Seattle SEA Seahawks"         
#> [15] "New England NEP Patriots Detroit DET Lions"      
#> [16] "Pittsburgh PIT Steelers Tampa Bay TBB Buccaneers"
```

<sup>Created on 2018-09-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

**EDIT**
You still got all relevant information via `read_html()`. You need to get the id from the drop-down and then parse the java-script string with all the salaries. I did the first part, the rest is up to you ;-)

```r
library(tidyverse, quietly = TRUE)
library(rvest, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
#> Lade nötiges Paket: xml2

url <- "https://rotogrinders.com/lineups/nfl?site=draftkings"
raw <- read_html(url) 

# helper function
parse_json <- function(x) tibble(name = x$name, importID = x$importId)

# get id from slates
raw %>%
  html_nodes(".slate-data") %>%
  html_attr(name = "value") %>%
  jsonlite::fromJSON() %>%
  purrr::map_df(parse_json)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>    name                                                importID
#>    <chr>                                               <chr>   
#>  1 1:00pm: Classic: 13 Games                           21505   
#>  2 8:20pm: Classic (Thu-Mon): 16 Games                 21576   
#>  3 1:00pm: Classic (Sun-Mon): 15 Games                 21586   
#>  4 1:00pm: Tiers (NFL Tiers): 14 Games                 21589   
#>  5 1:00pm: Classic (Early Only): 10 Games              21581   
#>  6 4:05pm: Classic (Afternoon Only): 3 Games           21630   
#>  7 4:25pm: Classic (Afternoon Turbo): 2 Games          21631   
#>  8 8:20pm: Classic (Primetime): 2 Games                21645   
#>  9 4:25pm: Showdown Captain Mode (DAL vs SEA): 1 Games 21632   
#> 10 8:20pm: Showdown Captain Mode (NE vs DET): 1 Games  21644

raw %>%
  html_nodes(".select") %>%
  html_nodes("script") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  stringr::str_squish() %>%
  substr(1, 1000)
#> [1] "window.slateSelect = window.createReactComponent(SlateSelectRadnor, { slates: {\"All Games\":{\"games\":[{\"scheduleId\":\"45755\",\"teamAwayId\":\"12\",\"teamHomeId\":\"3\"},{\"scheduleId\":\"45756\",\"teamAwayId\":\"23\",\"teamHomeId\":\"21\"},{\"scheduleId\":\"45757\",\"teamAwayId\":\"9\",\"teamHomeId\":\"8\"},{\"scheduleId\":\"45758\",\"teamAwayId\":\"25\",\"teamHomeId\":\"1\"},{\"scheduleId\":\"45759\",\"teamAwayId\":\"14\",\"teamHomeId\":\"19\"},{\"scheduleId\":\"45760\",\"teamAwayId\":\"2\",\"teamHomeId\":\"22\"},{\"scheduleId\":\"45761\",\"teamAwayId\":\"31\",\"teamHomeId\":\"26\"},{\"scheduleId\":\"45762\",\"teamAwayId\":\"7\",\"teamHomeId\":\"20\"},{\"scheduleId\":\"45763\",\"teamAwayId\":\"27\",\"teamHomeId\":\"10\"},{\"scheduleId\":\"45764\",\"teamAwayId\":\"18\",\"teamHomeId\":\"13\"},{\"scheduleId\":\"45765\",\"teamAwayId\":\"16\",\"teamHomeId\":\"15\"},{\"scheduleId\":\"45766\",\"teamAwayId\":\"28\",\"teamHomeId\":\"30\"},{\"scheduleId\":\"45767\",\"teamAwayId\":\"5\",\"teamHomeId\":\"29\"},{\"scheduleId\":\"45768\",\"teamAwayId\":\"17\",\"teamHomeId\":\"32\"},{\"scheduleId\":\"45769\",\"teamAwayId\":\"11\",\"teamHomeId\":\"6\"},{\"scheduleId\":\"45770\","
```

<sup>Created on 2018-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: The slate schedule does more than filter the schedule. It also changes salaries. While some salaries are the same across slates, others are not. I'm looking to pull the correct salaries for the slate that I want, which isn't updated unless you select the slate from the dropdown.

Comment: I've gotten the code to work, but I'm hoping you can help me understand something. When I inspect the page, it appears as if the script is within the `div` with id `#gamestat-filters`. The `div` with class `.select` appears to me to not include any `<script>` tag. The code works so I must be missing something. What am I missing?